# Typing error "Default export of the module has or is using private name" - switch from typescript v1.8 to 2

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ionic2, typescript1.8

I've updated my ionic app from beta 11 to rc0. So it means I've switched from angular2 rc4 to angular2 stable and from typescript 1.8 to 2.

I have a redux architecture and am using the Redux library.

This line of code is giving me the following error

```
export default combineReducers({
  user,songs,app
})
```

> error TS4082: Default export of the module has or is using private
>   name 'Reducer'.

Any idea on what's going on and how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error went away when I made an explicit import of *Reducer* from the redux library.

```
import { combineReducers, Reducer } from 'redux'
```

Comment: This creates another issue: an unused import

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with **Vue**. Basically I imported a module that internally used a class that was not exported. I just needed to export this class as well

Comment: How would you solve this when you have no control over the module with the private class?